# Simultaneous MSSQL connections result in locked resource sqljdbc_auth.dll

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, wildfly

Having an issue I cannot seem to fix

Been looking at related issues regarding sqljdbc_auth.dll load fails but they all seems to be related to the fact that the sqljdbc_auth.dll is not available from their running container. This is not the issue here

I have a WAR application deployed on a wildfly server. This application spawns several threads, which each creates a ms sql connection. This is all done at the same time which results in the sqljdbc_auth.dll being locked by the first thread using it

The log states the following when the second threads tryies to establish a connection

```
sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another classloader
```

What do I have to do to make sqljdbc_auth.dll availble for all threads in the same application?

Thanks

**Edit for the fast duplicate marker**

*You need to have a single SQL Server driver jar deployed in the application server itself, not a driver per web application*

I have a single SQL Server driver in my container. Im not sure what makes you think it is bundled in the WAR

*This has nothing to do with multiple threads, but multiple classloaders trying to load the same dll, which indicates that you are trying to load multiple versions of the JDBC driver*

Can you expand on this? The post you claim to be the answer im looking for does not help me at all in this regard. Moreover the answer in that post is concerning tomcat classloading

Lastly.
I dont know how you can mark a post duplicate after few minutes. Did you even read those posts? Bottom line, my problem still persists and I would like people to have the opportunity to help instead of instant marked as duplicate

Comment: You need to have a single SQL Server driver jar deployed in the application server itself, not a driver per web application. BTW: This has nothing to do with multiple threads, but multiple classloaders trying to load the same dll, which indicates that you are trying to load multiple versions of the JDBC driver.